# Linux C Programming - kill() and sleep()

Tags: c, linux, signals, sleep

I have some code that simply creates a child process and then the parent and child take turns doing math on a variable and output the results. I have it working now, but I accidentally discovered that it only worked when I put a sleep() before my kill() when putting a sleep in to observe the results on the file itself. Can anyone explain this behavior to me? Without sleep() the child process never runs. I'm using Linux on VM VirtualBox on Windows 8, and this is HW so I'm not allowed to use pipe().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

void sigHandler(int signo)
{
    signal(signo, sigHandler);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int file; 
    int x = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    char filename[17] = "sigpong_temp.txt";
    file = creat(filename, S_IRWXU);
    fprintf(stdout, "initial value %d\n", x);
    const int csize = 10;
    char c[csize];

    sprintf(c, "%d", x);
    write(file, &c, strlen(c));
    close(file);
    file = open(filename, O_RDWR);
    signal(SIGUSR1, sigHandler);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            lseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
            read(file, &c, csize);
            x = atoi(c);
            x++;
            sprintf(c, "%d", x);
            fprintf(stdout, "Parent: x =\t%d\n", x);
            lseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
            write(file, &c, strlen(c));
            sleep(1);
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            pause();
        } 
        close(file);
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            pause();            
            lseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
            read(file, &c, csize);
            x = atoi(c);
            x = x * 10;
            sprintf(c, "%d", x);
            fprintf(stdout, "Child: x =\t%d\n", x);
            lseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
            write(file, &c, strlen(c));
            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
        }
        close(file);                
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably a race condition. Both the parent/child are trying to kill each other, and the sleep(1) pauses the parent process long enough for the child to execute and do its kill first.

Comment: Why are you using `signal` and `kill`?

Comment: @MarcB The child has to wait for the signal from the parent, that's what the `pause` is doing.
@anthony-arnold That's the assignment.

Comment: True, but there's no guarantees that the child will get executed far enough to actually REACH the pause() call before the parent gets to its kill().

Comment: Ah, that must be it! Thanks! Is there a better way to make sure the child doesn't get and ignore a `kill` because it hasn't reached its `pause`?

Comment: block the signal before fork()ing, then use sigsuspend() rather than pause()

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21070415/63743) which demostrates how to do this properly by blocking and using sigsuspend.  The goal of the program is much the same as this.